# Symfony 3 How to Unit Test your Forms with VichUploaderBundle field

Tags: forms, types, phpunit, symfony-3.2

Someone did a unit form test with VichFileTypefield?.
When i run my form type test, i get:

```
Argument 1 passed to Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType::__construct() must implement interface Vich\UploaderBundle\Storage\StorageInterface
```

that because

```
public function __construct(
    StorageInterface $storage,
    UploadHandler $handler,
    TranslatorInterface $translator
)
```

how can I pass these?